# trigonometric limit factoring

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, rationalising-denominator

I have this problem that I can't solve:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{3x-\sin 2x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$$

Tried to multiply by the conjugate, so I can get rid of the squareroot on the denominator, but I am stuck after that. Can't use L'Hopital, only factoring:

$$\frac{3x-\sin 2x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sqrt{1+\cos x}}=\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}$$

rewrite using trig identities and cancel the sqroot on the denominator.
After that, I don't know how to continue:

$$\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}$$

PS: Any book that help with this types of problems? Thanks

Comment: Can you use latex so we aren't reliant on looking at the image? I'm assuming sen is $\sin?$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also do you know what $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is? If you don't I don't see a way to do the problem. But once you multiply by the conjugate you can use this limit and solve it.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed sorry don't know how to use laTex(just did it), and sen is sine.

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer my previous question about whether $\lim_{x \to 0}\sin(x)/x$ is allowed (technically, it can use L'Hopital's rule but sometimes it is given.) You can use the double angle formula to turn $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ so the problem reduces to finding $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}.$

Comment: Tried Taylor expansion? Also are you restricted from using L'hospital? You should be getting $+\sqrt 2$ as the limit from the right

Comment: For $0\le x\le \pi/2$, $\sqrt {1 - \cos x}  = \sqrt 2 \sin (x/2)$. Thus you have to compute $$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt 2 \frac{{3 - 2\frac{{\sin (2x)}}{{2x}}}}{{\frac{{\sin (x/2)}}{{x/2}}}}.
$$

Comment: if you edit your question showing where you are stuck, I'll write an answer

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed  sorry for the late reply, Yes! that's allowed, that property equals to 1, right?

Comment: @ayan we didn't study Taylor expansions yet. For this instance, can't use L'Hopital's rule. I'm taking Calculus I course.

Comment: @gary thanks for editing my question, sorry i don't get what you wrote.

Comment: @SineoftheTime already edited! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Continue from where you're stuck; since $x\to0^+$ you have:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sin x}$$
Now, I assume both limits exist and are finite:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sin x}=3\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\sqrt{1+\cos x}-\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}\sqrt{1+\cos x} $$
The first limit is $3 \sqrt 2$, whereas the second is $2\sqrt 2$:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}\sqrt{1+\cos x}=2\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}\frac{x}{\sin x}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{1+\cos x}=2\sqrt 2 $$
Hence you conclude that:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(3x-\sin 2x)\sqrt{1+\cos x}}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x}}=3\sqrt 2 -2\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2 $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Step by step :

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{3x-\sin2x}{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(3x-\sin2x)(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}
{(\sqrt{1-\cos x})(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(3x-\sin2x)(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(3x-\sin2x)(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}{\sqrt{\sin^2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(3x-\sin2x)(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}{|\sin x|}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{(3x-\sin2x)(\sqrt{1+\cos x})}{\sin x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{3x-\sin2x}{\sin x}(\sqrt{1+\cos x})\\
&=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{3-\frac{\sin2x}x}{\frac{\sin x}x}(\sqrt{1+\cos x})\\
&=\frac{3-\lim\frac{\sin2x}x}{\lim\frac{\sin x}x}(\lim\sqrt{1+\cos x})\\
&=\frac{3-2}{1}\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt2
\end{align*}
$$

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{\sin x}x=1.$$

Comment: Thank you! why are you getting downvoted? You divided by x, so do you get rid of the x multiplying the 3, then separated into two limits the terms?